# Python: Concatenate list of lists in the algebraic way

Tags: python, list, python-itertools

In maths, when you have two sets of words *A={foo,bar}* and *B={x,y}*, then the algebraic (or each-to-each) product is *AB={foox,fooy,barx,bary}*. I would like a similar thing in Python. Given two sets of words (= list of lists):

```
A = [ [0,1], [2,3] ]
B = [ [4,5], [6,7] ]
```

I would like to concatenate them each-to-each:

```
AB = [ [0,1,4,5], [0,1,6,7], [2,3,4,5], [2,3,6,7] ]
```

That itself is not so difficult, it can be done with `product`:

```
AB = [ a+b for (a,b) in itertools.product(A,B) ]
```

However, I have a list of "sets" (aka, list of lists of lists)

```
A = [ [0,1], [2,3] ]
B = [ [4,5], [6,7] ]
C = [ [4,5], [6,7] ]
SETS = [A,B,C]
```

Now I can do manually

```
ABC = [ a+b+c for (a,b,c) in itertools.product(A,B,C) ]
```

But I can't do that if I have 20 sets to concatenate. So, how to write a definition of `ABC` that would use only `SETS` and would accept any size of it?

Comment: What should the output look like? Is it a full concatenization of the inner lists or do those get cons'd?

Comment: @wheaties It's a full concatenation. So for instance `SETS=[ [0,1] ]*20` should give all possible binary strings of length `20`.

Comment: "sets" are not also known as a list of lists of lists, and there's no need for your variable name to SHOUT.

Comment: @DSM There is no need for variable names to be shouted, but it's common style to shout CONSTANT names.

Comment: @delnan: I'll stand corrected if these are constants.

Comment: @DSM sorry, a habit from maths. Sets and other more complex stuff is uppercase, simple objects such as numbers or words are lowecase.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
ABC = [ sum(z, []) for z in itertools.product(*SETS) ]
```

`product(*SETS)` basically does `product(A, B, C)`. The technical term is [argument unpacking](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).

`sum(z, [])` basically does `a + b + c + []`.

**EDIT**:

As smart people said in the comments `sum` isn't a best way to join a list of lists. O(n^2) time complexity is pretty brutal.

To quote a [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum):

> For some use cases, there are good alternatives to sum(). The
>   preferred, fast way to concatenate a sequence of strings is by calling
>   ''.join(sequence). To add floating point values with extended
>   precision, see math.fsum(). To concatenate a series of iterables,
>   consider using itertools.chain().

That's better:

```
from itertools import chain, product
ABC = [ list(chain(*z)) for z in product(*SETS) ]
```

or, if two argument unpackings is one argument unpacking too many:

```
ABC = [ list(chain.from_iterable(z)) for z in product(*SETS) ]
```

or, if you're into `map`:

```
ABC = map(list, map(chain.from_iterable, product(*SETS)))
```

Comment: `sum(z, [])` takes `sum(len(y) for y in z)**2`  time. It's also arguably bad style to use `sum` for non-numbers (it's explicitly prohibited for strings).

Comment: @delnan yes, there's the `itertools.chain`. The missing step for me was obviously unpacking. I've never seen it!

Comment: So it seems that the way to go is `[list(itertools.chain(*z)) for z in itertools.product(*SETS)]`

Answer (score 1):

Using argument unpacking, you can abstract over the number of sets: `itertools.product(*SETS)`. Furthermore, you can define a helper function to concatenate a variable number of lists (efficiently):

```
def concat(seqs):
    result = []
    for seq in seqs:
        result.extend(seq)
    return result
```

In summary: `[concat(prod) for prod in itertools.product(*SETS)]`

Answer (score 1):

First, use the `*` operator to unpack `SETS` for the `itertools.product()` function argument.

```
    itertools.product(*SET)
```

Then using `import operator`, concatenate the result from that:

```
    product = [ reduce(operator.add, tuple) for tuple in itertools.product(*SET) ]
```

This works because if the `tuple` variable is `([0,1], [4,5], [8,9])`, `reduce(operator.add, tuple)` still gives you `[0,1,4,5,8,9]`.